# Animating Tab Bar page switching

Tags: iphone

I have tab based application  which also have Navigation controllers, When the user in Navigation controller view (I have hide the bottom tab bar when the user in navigation controller view),i want to take the user to specific tab with some animation,how can i achieve this?

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [tutorial on the iDev Recipes blog](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/17/twitter-app-tab-bar-animation/) about this which you might find helpful.